# Dúvida sobre retorno de dados em POO PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu estou aprendendo sobre a programação orientada a objetos no PHP, as classes, hierarquias e etc. 
Lendo alguns tópicos aqui mesmo no stackoverflow eu encontrei a solução para o meu problema com a classe de controle de usuários, mas eu fiquei com uma dúvida em relação a isso.

A classe seria:

```
class UserService
{
protected $_email;    // using protected so they can be accessed
protected $_password; // and overidden if necessary
protected $_user;     // stores the user data

public function __construct($email, $password) 
{
   $this->_email = $email;
   $this->_password = $password;
}
public function login()
{
    $user = $this->_checkCredentials();
    if ($user) {
        $this->_user = $user; // store it so it can be accessed later
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
        return $user['id'];
    }
    return false;
}

protected function _checkCredentials()
{

    /* Faz a rotina para verificar se o usuário está no banco de dados*/
    /* e se a senha confere */

    /* Se OK retorna os dados do usuário, se não, retorna false */

}   
}
```

Eu estou em dúvida em como usar essa classe caso eu queira retornar apenas o nome de usuário por exemplo.

Para logar o usuário eu entendi, seria:

```
session_start();
include("class.user.php");

$user = new UserService($_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);
```

Mas e se eu quiser retornar apenas o nome (ou algum outro dado) do usuário já logado, sem ter que passar os parâmetros "email" e "password" novamente?

Eu teria que criar uma função dentro da classe para que eu passasse o ID do usuário armazenado na $_SESSION e a classe retornaria os dados, mas eu teria que instanciar a classe usando o "new" novamente?

Por exemplo, na classe, acrescentar:

```
public function getUserName($uID)
{
   /* Verifica se o usuário está logado e busca o nome no DB */       
}
```

E no arquivo principal (considerando que o usuário já tenha sido logado anteriormente):

```
session_start();
include("class.user.php");

$user = new UserService();

$userName = $user->getUserName($_SESSION['user_id']);

echo $userName;
```

Isso está correto?

EDIT: Essa classe é só um rascunho do que eu pretendo fazer, eu compreendo que é necessário corrigir alguns trechos, sanitizar os campos, encriptar a senha e etc, essa é apenas para demonstrar minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você setar `session_start()` no `__construct`, caso após login você já colocar a `$_SESSION['nome']` aí ficaria assim:

```
  public function getUserName()
  {
    return $_SESSION['nome'];
  }
```

Comment: Certo, mas ao chamar a classe eu preciso chamar o "new" ou instanciar a classe diretamente?

Comment: Se a classe não for static você sempre tem que instanciar com o new. se ela for static você só precisa fazer assim UserService::getUserName(); não esquecer que tem que da um include no classe no começo do arquivo.